# vim highlight - which order the files are loaded

Tags: vim, highlight

I have

```
colorscheme slate
```

followed by

```
highlight Search term=reverse cterm=reverse
highlight IncSearch term=reverse cterm=reverse
```

in ~/.vimrc file. But when I say `:verbose hi Search` in vim, it gives me

```
:verbose hi Search 
Search         xxx term=reverse ctermfg=248 ctermbg=12
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim72/colors/slate.vim
```

I don't understand why my own highlight overriding of Search does not kick in here. When I say `:scriptnames`, I get

```
~/.vimrc
```

at position 8 and

```
/usr/share/vim/vim72/colors/slate.vim
```

at position 9. I don't understand why Search highlight definition in `.vimrc` is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to modify the scheme, copy the file to ~/.vim/colors/ and just edit it.

Comment: Does loading Vim without the (hi Search and IncSearch <- your lines) and then typing them manually, produce the same result?

Comment: @ldigas: Yes, manually typing them gives the desired result.

Comment: @YogiSharma - Something is overwriting your setting then. Could you paste your _vimrc and output of :scriptnames (more important) here so we can try to determine what that is exactly?

Comment: `:help initialization` and `:help 'runtimepath'` will make you understand how Vim starts up and in what order scripts are read.